# Set value on additional attribute in @ManyToMany relationship table spring boot

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have a @ManyToMany relationship table between User and Diet classes. The table (UserIsOnADiet) has 2 additional columns: fromDate (starting the diet) and toDate (ending). When a user enrolls on a diet, I want to set a value on the fromDate attribute, since it has a not-null constraint. How can I do that? Here is my code:

Class User

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer username_id;
    private String username;
   
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "is_on",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "username_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "diet_id"))
    private Set<Diet> userIsOnADiet;
```

Class Diet

```
@Entity
public class Diet {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer diet_id;
    private String diet_name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "userIsOnADiet")
    public List<User> users;
```

UserService:

```
@Override
    public User updateDiets(Integer id, Diet d) {
        User u = this.findById(id);
        Set<Diet> userDiets = u.getUserIsOnADiet();
        userDiets.add(d); 
//        LocalDate fromDate = LocalDate.now();
//        UserIsOnADiet userIsOnADiet = new UserIsOnADiet();
//        userIsOnADiet.setFromDate(fromDate);

// I want to do something like this, but I cannot save User with null value on fromDate,
//and cannot set fromDate before creating a tuple in the database.

        return this.userRepository.save(u);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to map your join table to an additional entity, and replace @ManyToMany association with two bidirectional @OneToMany associations.

See [The best way to map a many-to-many association with extra columns when using JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/)

> For a simple many-to-many database relationship, you can use the @ManyToMany JPA annotation and, therefore, hide the join table.
>
> However, sometimes you need more than the two Foreign Key columns in the join table, and, for this purpose, you need to replace the @ManyToMany association with two bidirectional @OneToMany associations. Unlike unidirectional @OneToMany, the bidirectional relationship is the best way to map a one-to-many database relationship that requires a collection of Child elements on the parent side