Spring JPA - using extra table in @ManyToMany relationship
I have a database structure like this:
entity tables:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS city
(
     city_id VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
     name    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS store
(
     store_id VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
     name     VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS region
(
     region_id VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
     name      VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);


and links (associations) tables:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS store_region
(
  store_region_id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
  store_id        VARCHAR(255) REFERENCES store(store_id),
  region_id       VARCHAR(255) REFERENCES region(region_id),
  created_at      timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  UNIQUE (store_id, region_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS store_city
(
  store_region_id bigint REFERENCES store_region(store_region_id),
  city_id         VARCHAR(255) REFERENCES city(city_id),
  created_at      timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY(store_region_id, city_id)
);

Can I describe this structure in Java classes using Spring JPA annotations?
Can I add store_region table to @JoinTable ?
Simplified code for better understanding:
public class CityModel {

    @Id
    private String cityId;
    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "store_city",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "city_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "store_id") }
    )
    private Set<StoreModel> storeModels = new HashSet<>();

}

public class StoreModel {

    @Id
    private String storeId;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "store_city",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "store_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "city_id") }
    )
    private Set<CityModel> cityModels = new HashSet<>();
}

We want to save the relationship between the city and the store in the database only for those entities that already have a relationship between the store and the region.

Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70674224/set-value-on-additional-attribute-in-manytomany-relationship-table-spring-boot.
